# System.IdentityModel is unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, reference, .net-4.0

I create test MVC 3 project on `.Net 4.0`. Try to install **Auth0 nuget package**. This package require `System.IdentityModel.dll`. But i can't finish installing of package as `System.IdentityModel.dll` is unavailable in the project.

I try to add this reference manually:

Go by this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.IdentityModel.dll` and add reference, seems all is well, but finally reference is **unavailable** again. I don't know how to resolve this problem. Need your Help.

---

> Error: Failed to add reference to 'System.IdentityModel'. Please make
>   sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache
>
> ---

Update : I try to create MVC4 project on `.Net 4.0` and can't add `System.IdentityModel.dll` to project also

Comment: @hutchonoid, possible, but why it exists in assemblies for framework .Net 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.IdentityModel is available for Framework 4.
You should add it in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) using GACUTIL http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.100).aspx
for example:

gacutil /i mydll.dll

Also you can try install a older version of Auth0 and Auth0-aspnet. v1.2.1 don't require IdentityModel.

You can install the package from the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Auth0-ASPNET -Version 1.2.1
```

Dependencies:

Auth0 (≥ 1.1.0) and ClaimsCookie (≥ 1.2.0)